# What is the correct way to frame this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, usage

What would be the correct usage?

> The box of chocolates is **over**.

OR

> The box of chocolates is **finished**.

Comment: The box of chocolates is finished

Answer (score 2):

**The movie is over, the play is over.**

Meaning: the movie has come to an end, the play has come to an end.

**The box of chocolates is finished**. = All the chocolates have been eaten.

With regard to consuming chocolates from a box, **one generally would not use "is over"** because "is over" refers to an activity or thing occurring in time that has come to an end.

The movie is over. [We were watching it and it has finished or come to an end.]

Answer (score 0):

People would understand both, but you should use finished in this instance.

The box of chocolates is finished.

You are describing the box itself, if you were describing something like the time you could use over:

The time for eating chocolates was over.

Comment: What if it was something like lunch is over. Would saying lunch is finished still be better ?

Comment: Not at all, in that instance I would use over. It is tricky finished vs over, I would try stick to, if it's a tangible thing, a packet of biscuits, a cup of tea etc then use finished, if it's more of a time passage then use either, play time for the children was over, lunch time had finished, lunch time was over. Usually I hate people saying this as it's not always helpful but this to me is one of those cases where mostly it doesn't matter and both work and neither are better English or more likely to be used, use both and see what others use. I hope that's somewhat helpful.